# VS2010 Debugger will not start with solution comprising multiple newly translated VS2008 3.5 projects (now 2010 .net4)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, debugging

So, kind of vague question, and I'm afraid I really can't be very specific. I have a solution previously in VS2008, .net 3.5. We wanted to upgrade to 2010 .net 4.0 to make use of MEF. The project is a mixture of C# and c++/CLI. After lots of finagling with project settings, I can finally get the project to build. However, when I try to launch it with debugging, absolutely nothing happens. It build the project, but then says "Build Succeeded" (Debug AND Release)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible the app is starting but immediately exiting?  Have you looked in the event logs to see if there are any errors?  What does Visual Studio's Output window display?

Comment: There is absolutely no output whatsoever. It's as if I had only told it to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's the fix? No clue. Instead of using the .net 4.0 MEF, I instead found the latest pre-.net MEF source project and included it in my 3.5 project. Problem solved =)